# Rendering Datatable in Flask very slow

Tags: python, flask, datatable

How can I optimize my datatable rendering. My PG table contains 35k+ rows, the pandas dataframe ins't that slow but the Datatable takes very long time to get rendered in my HTML page :

## app.py

```
@app.route('/html_one', methods=["POST","GET"])
def referentiel_communes():
    r = requests.get('https://api/', params=payload, verify=False)   
    data_dict = r.json()    
    data_str = json.dumps(data_dict)
    df = pd.read_json(data_str) 
    print(df)
    return render_template('referentiel_communes.html', tables=[df.to_html(table_id = 'html_one',classes="display table table-striped table-bordered")], titles=df.columns.values, header="true")
```

## HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    {% for table in tables %}
            <!-- {{titles[loop.index]}} -->
            {{ table|safe }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

## JS

```
var html_one = $('#html_one').DataTable({
    select: true,
    fixedHeader: true,

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on in your view function.

1. You are downloading data from an API
2. You are converting json to string and then to a dataframe.
3. You are rendering out the data frame in html
4. Then you are sending all of that back to the browser

When you consider just the network delay from waiting for the external API to then waiting for that to get transferred back to the client, that could be a significant part of the wait. Also consider that 35,000 rows when rendered out in HTML could be 40-50 MB which takes a decent amount of time to move around in a network situation even for fast connections.

If you create a very basic HTML page with the following data duplicated 35,000 times you get a web page that is 5 Mb in size, which is considered large for an HTML page.

```html
<tr>
  <td>Hi</td>
  <td>Sample Data</td>
</tr>
```

Imagine how much larger that would be if each row of your data frame contained much more data?

There are a lot of options for speeding things up, but the basics are:

- Don't want a view function to rely on an external API if you can avoid it
- You probably want to paginate large data sets
- Send data back to the browser in less bulky formats than HTML (JSON or even CSV) and allow the client to parse it. This reduces the network lag of moving a large file.